# Are there any best practices for implementing Java-types vs SQL-types mapping different from default ones

Tags: java, sql, jpa, informix

I'm working in JPA 2.0 project generating entities to approximately 100 tables (Informix). My requirement tells me that artifacts must provide a clean solution to manage data type conversion this way:

- Float SQL type must be implemented as a Float Java Type not default Java Double type.
- Date SQL type must be implemented as Calendar Java Type not default Java SQL Date type.

The easy-way IMO would be create a utility class providing properly casting and use it where necessary.

Are there any tools or similar that could help out to automate this task?

Comment: Why would you want to lose precision by mapping SQL FLOAT to Java `float`?  SQL FLOAT is represented internally as C `double` aka Java `double`; SQL SMALLFLOAT corresponds to Java `float`.

Comment: hello Jonathan, we are in proof of concept stage at the moment, you're right, casting to float implies a loss of precision but it is something that somebody (not me) defined in the document,
maybe considering to use non default values in a given moment.

Comment: Gut feel: someone misunderstood what SQL FLOAT means, at least in Informix SQL.  It is more likely a mistake than a deliberate decision.

Answer (score 1):

If you annotate `java.util.Calendar` fields with [`@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/TemporalType.html), then the generated SQL should be of type `DATE`, for example:

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name = "SOME_DATE")
private Calendar someDate;
```

Additionally, you can specify how to generate a column's DDL with [`columnDefinition`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Column.html#columnDefinition%28%29):

```
@Column(name = "SOME_FLOAT", columnDefinition = "FLOAT(8)")
private Float someFloat;
```